# Libgdx Android set screen resolution

Tags: android, libgdx

I have not found any way to successfully set a screen resolution on my android device.
when i run my libgdx app on my galaxy note, it automatically sets the applications screen resolution to 800x600 while my phone (Galaxy note) got a 1280x800 resolution. there are no scaling. just a small screen with huge black boarders around.

I have tried to use Gdx.graphics.setDisplayMode to force a greater resolution but without any success.

my application is very simple. i followed:
http://code.google.com/p/libgdx/wiki/ProjectSetup
and added SpriteBatch and Textures from:
http://code.google.com/p/libgdx/wiki/SpriteBatch

I will only use textures in this app. what have i missed? what is wrong?

the following code:

```
    com.badlogic.gdx.Graphics.DisplayMode[] modes;
    modes = Gdx.graphics.getDisplayModes();
    for (com.badlogic.gdx.Graphics.DisplayMode mode : modes) {
            System.out.println(mode);
    }
```

Only give the line: 480x320, bpp 0, hz: 0

I get a message "MALI_NO_HANDLE in function _mali_base_common_mem_alloc because the requested_size is 0" can this be related?
any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I put this in the AndroidManifest.xml and it seemed to fix the issue:

```
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="4" android:targetSdkVersion="13" />
```

Hope this works for you.

Comment: Glad to be of service, took me weeks to figure that one out.

Answer (score 1):

You can not set the screen resolution on Android, as documented in the Javadocs you used (Graphics#setDisplayMode).